# Clipping vs Joining Polygons to Polygons, which sum of Area should I trust?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two polygon layers, layer 1 and layer 2. I want to know the sum of the areas of layer 2 that are completely inside of layer 1 to include the sum of the intersecting portions of areas from layer 2.  Each item in layer 1 is an area that is larger than each area in layer 2. There are many more items in layer 2.

I first used Clip on layer 2, with layer 1. I calculated the sum of the shape area of the output.

Second I joined layer 1 to the Clip output and selected the sum option.

The summed area of the join output, however, does not match the clip.

Why do these not match? Which should I trust?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please be aware that a Q&A site like this is very different to a discussion forum.

Comment: Could you clarify which Tools you are using? And perhaps add screenshots of the layers and attribute tables

Comment: Do this in 2 steps - intersect tool; calculate geometry (area).

Answer (score 3):

The spatial join takes its values from all the polygons that intersect it. So you should be aware that the joined polygons will not necessarily be inside. Clipping is therefore a good idea in your case, as your new polygons will be within the first layer.

However, my hypothesis is that you are working with shapefile, and the area value stored in a shapefile is not updated when you clip it (contrary to the geodatabase). Therfore you must first update the area of your polygons before you make the join. This can be done by clicking on the area header in the attribute table and selection "Calculate geometry".

Alternatively, I would suggest that you use "intersect" instead of clip+join, but if your output is in shapefile, you will also have to update the "shape_area" field.

Comment: The "calculate geometry" selection is grayed out for the clip and intersect outputs. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you define the coordinate system of your shapefile ?

Comment: I see that the coordinate system is defined in all shapefiles, though I did not define them myself. I checked this in properties -> source

Comment: You need to add an area field (double), then try Calculate Geometry on that.

Answer (score -3):

Are all the items in Layer 2 the same type? I use a program called Cartographica & the only way I can achieve the result you are seeking is to perform a "difference" function between the various layers that are all the same type.

I am fairly new to GIS as well and there aren't many forums for Cartographica so I have to do a lot of testing.

Comment: He's asking how to do it using Arcgis-desktop

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please take the [Tour] to better understand how things work here in GIS SE.